# Spring Boot returning null when a url is defined as value

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I am defining key values in application properties. It is reading all other values correctly but when I give a url as value it returns null. Any suggestion why.

I tried single quote, double quote and @"" but everytime it giving null for base url

a screen shot of application.properties file

```
server.port=8095
baseUrl=https://localhost:8080/api/gettingdata/singlevalue/employee
applicationId=APPLICATION_ID
userName=user_Name
password=pass_Word
directoryId=Directory_Id
```

in the above case it returns null for baseUrl value

Comment: "it returns null" - *What* returns `null`? Could you post some code?

Comment: Do you have multiple application.properties files maybe? A regular one and one for testing?

Comment: which version spring boot? actually it is working for me, can you show the code how are you reading it ?

Comment: Can confirm, this is working for me. It's likely a typo in how the configuration properties are implemented in the code.

Comment: There is notthing wrong in your properties definition. Show how you are trying to read the proerty.

Comment: Thank you all. I think sometimes Eclipse acts weirdly, I restarted it and now its working fine